# Is the probability density for c = np.random.random() and d = 30 * np.random.random() same?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, python

`import numpy as np`

`c = np.random.random()`

Then we know *c* is uniformly distributed over the half-open interval [0,1) and the probability density function (pdf) of *c* is given by,
$$
p(c) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-0}~\text{ for}~ 0 \leq c < 1\\
0,~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, if we generate d as follows:

`scalar = 30`

`d = scalar * np.random.random()`

then what is the pdf of *d* i.e. *p(d)*?

Comment: The latter one (d) can reach a value of 20, for example. The first one (c) cannot. So there is a clear difference.

Comment: In general if the density of $X$ is $f_X(x)$ for $a \le x \lt b$ then the density of $Y=kX$ for some $k>0$ is $f_Y(y) = \frac1k f_X\left(\frac y k \right)$ for $ka \le y \lt kb$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d also has a uniform distribution, but now it's on the range $[0,30)$. So
$$
p(d) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{30-0}~\text{ for}~ 0 \leq d < 30\\
0,~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$